# Show that $E_{ij}ME_{kl}= m_{kj}E_{il}$ in $V=M_{2x2}^R$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Basically I need to prove this:

> Show that $E_{ij}ME_{kl}= m_{kj}E_{il}$ in $V=M_{2x2}^R$

Where $E$ is one of the matrices in the standard basis.

However, I can't find a way to do this without listing all the options. I'm sure there is a better way...

Any tips?

Comment: A hint: try it for different values of $i,j,k,l$ : it will surely give you an idea...

Comment: Recall that the standard matrix basis can be written in terms of the standard vector basis, e.g. $E_{ij}=e_ie_j^T$. Making that replacement on the LHS of the equation will lead you to to desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$$E_{kl}$ sends the $l$th standard basis vector to the $k$th and the rest to zero. (And it is the unique matrix with this property.) Note the intuitive cancellation law:
$$E_{k\cancel l}e_{\cancel l} = e_k$$

$M$ sends the $k$th to the sum of $m_{nk}$ times the $n$th. (Generalization of the above law/definition of matrix product.)

When applying $E_{ij}$, only the $j$th vector contributes and you get $m_{jk}$ times the $i$th.

Composing everything, $E_{ij}ME_{kl}$ sends the $l$th to $m_{jk}$ times the $i$th.

Yet $m_{jk}E_{il}$ is the unique matrix with this property. Thus:
$$E_{ij}ME_{kl} = m_{jk}E_{il}$$

**Alternatively,** you can start by observing that we have the cancellation law:
$$E_{k\cancel l}E_{\cancel lm} = E_{km}$$
and we get zero if those two indices do not match.

Then write $M=\sum_{x,y} m_{xy}E_{xy}$ and we have:
$$E_{ij}ME_{kl}=\sum_{x,y} E_{ij}m_{xy}E_{xy}E_{kl}=m_{jk}E_{il}$$
because the cancellation law says that only one term survives.

Comment: That is, the RHS should have $m_{jk}$ and not $m_{kj}$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks your descriptions were very helpful.